# Why I am getting different predictions for manual polynomial expansion and using the R `poly` function?

Tags: r, regression, polynomial

Why I am getting different predictions for manual polynomial expansion and using the R `poly` function?

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- runif(10)
plot(x,y,ylim=c(-0.5,1.5))
grid()

# xp is a grid variable for ploting
xp <- seq(-3,3,by=0.01)
x_exp <- data.frame(f1=x,f2=x^2)
fit <- lm(y~.-1,data=x_exp)
xp_exp <- data.frame(f1=xp,f2=xp^2)
yp <- predict(fit,xp_exp)
lines(xp,yp)

# using poly function
fit2 <- lm(y~ poly(x,degree=2) -1)
yp <- predict(fit2,data.frame(x=xp))
lines(xp,yp,col=2)
```

[image]

My attempt:

- It seems to be a problem with intercept, when I fit the model with intercept, i.e., no `-1` in model `formula`, the two lines are the same. But why without the intercept the two lines are different?
- Another "fix" is using `raw` polynomial expansion instead of orthogonal polynomial. If we change the code into `fit2 = lm(y~ poly(x,degree=2, raw=T) -1)`, will make 2 lines the same. But why?

Comment: This is off topic from your question, but you are often very open to commentary.  When reading your code, the first thing I notice is that you use `=` and `<-` for assignment inconsistently.  I really would not do this, it's not exactly confusing, but it adds lots of visual noise to your code for no benefit.  You should settle on one or the other to use in your personal code, and just stick with it.

Comment: thanks for helping me on coding! question fixed. @MatthewDrury

Comment: Random follow-up tip for making `<-` less of a hassle to type: `alt+-`.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam thanks for coding tip. I love key board short cuts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you correctly note the original difference is because in the first case you use the "raw" polynomials while in the second case you use the orthogonal polynomials. Therefore if the later `lm` call was altered into: `fit3<-lm(y~ poly(x,degree=2, raw = TRUE) -1)` we would get the same results between  `fit` and `fit3`. The reason *why* we get the same results in this case is "trivial"; we fit the exact same model as we fitted with `fit<-lm(y~.-1,data=x_exp)`, no surprises there.

One can easily check that the model matrices by the two models are the same `all.equal( model.matrix(fit), model.matrix(fit3) , check.attributes= FALSE) #  TRUE`).

---

What is more interesting is why you will get the same plots when using an intercept. The first thing to notice is that, when fitting a model with an intercept

- In the case of `fit2` we simply move the model predictions vertically; the actual shape of the curve is the same.
- On the other hand including an intercept in the case of `fit` results into not only a different line in terms of vertical placement but with a whole different shape overall.

We can easily see that by simply appending the following fits on the existing plot.

```
fit_b<-lm(y~. ,data=x_exp)
yp=predict(fit_b,xp_exp)
lines(xp,yp, col='green', lwd = 2)

fit2_b<-lm(y~ poly(x,degree=2, raw = FALSE) )
yp=predict(fit2_b,data.frame(x=xp))
lines(xp,yp,col='blue')
```

[image]

OK... Why were the no-intercept fits different while the intercept-including fits are the same? The catch is once again on the orthogonality condition.

In the case of `fit_b` the model matrix used contains non-orthogonal elements, the Gram matrix `crossprod( model.matrix(fit_b) )` is far from diagonal; in the case of `fit2_b` the elements are orthogonal (`crossprod( model.matrix(fit2_b) )` is effectively diagonal).

As such in the case of `fit` when we expand it to include an intercept in `fit_b` we changed the off-diagonal entries of the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) $X^TX$ and thus the resulting fit is different as a whole (different curvature, intercept, etc.) in comparison with the fit provided by `fit`. In the case of `fit2` though when we expand it to include an intercept as in `fit2_b` we only append a column that is already orthogonal to the columns we had, the orthogonality is [*against the constant polynomial of degree 0*](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/poly.html). This simply results on vertically moving our fitted line by the intercept. This is why the plots are different.

The interesting *by-question* is why the `fit_b` and `fit2_b` are the same; after all the model matrices from `fit_b` and `fit2_b` are not the same *in face value*. Here we just need to remember that ultimately `fit_b` and `fit2_b` have the same information. `fit2_b` is just a linear combination of the `fit_b` so essentially their resulting fits will be the same. The differences observed in the fitted coefficient reflects the linear recombination of the values of `fit_b` in order to get them orthogonal. (see G. Grothendieck answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484053) too for different example.)

Comment: +2.5 thanks for great answer. For the final graph, I learned from @kjetilb halvorsen: One more abstract way of describing this is that the model itself only depends on a certain linear subspace, namely the column space defined by the design matrix. But the parameters, depend not only on this subspace, but on the basis for that subspace, given by the specific variables used, that is, the columns itself. Predictions from the model, for instance, will only depend on the linear subspace, not on the choosen basis.