# Need help with Feature Engineering

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering

I'm new to data science, and am working on projects to develop my skills. I'm currently working on the [Loan Prediction practice competition](https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-loan-prediction-iii/) offered by Analytics Vidhya.The goal is to build a predictive model that will determine whether a loan will be approved or not.

So far, my models (logistic regression, random forest) do not perform any better than simply using the applicant's credit history as a predictor.

I've read through the provided tutorial (I don't have high enough rep to include all the links): `https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/complete-tutorial-learn-data-science-python-scratch-2/` which details the same results. The tutorial mentions that feature engineering will be important for this (and most) projects. I've found a few other resources for feature engineering ( `http://data-informed.com/how-to-improve-machine-learning-tricks-and-tips-for-feature-engineering/` and http://adataanalyst.com/machine-learning/comprehensive-guide-feature-engineering/ ) being the most helpful) but I'm still unable to build a model with higher accuracy.

The variables included in the data set are:

```
Variable          Description
-------------     -----------------
Loan_ID           Unique Loan ID
Gender            Male/ Female
Married           Applicant married (Y/N)
Dependents        Number of dependents
Education         Applicant Education (Graduate/ Under Graduate)
Self_Employed     Self employed (Y/N)
ApplicantIncome   Applicant income
CoapplicantIncome Coapplicant income
LoanAmount        Loan amount in thousands
Loan_Amount_Term  Term of loan in months
Credit_History    credit history meets guidelines
Property_Area     Urban/Semi Urban/Rural
Loan_Status       Loan approved (Y/N)
```

I've first multiplied **LoanAmount** by 1000, to have the value in dollars.

I've tried creating the following new features:

**TotalIncome** = ApplicantIncome + CoapplicantIncome

**Monthly_Payment** = LoanAmount / Loan_Amount_Term

**Payment_Ratio** = Monthly_Payment / TotalIncome

**household_size** = the number of people in the household, derived from marital status and number of dependents

I also found that many of the continuous variables (LoanAmount, TotalIncome, Payment_Ratio) are right-skewed and have transformed them by taking the log.

None of these changes have had any effect. It seems that no matter what variables I include in my model, it will not achieve better accuracy than the model that only considers Credit_History.

Are there any obvious features I've overlooked?

What should I try next?

Comment: Did you try interactions?

Comment: No. I'll look at that and update my question.

Answer (score 0):

People usually start feature engineering with different basis expansions. Such as polynomial expansion, splines, Fourier basis expansion etc.

Here are some related posts

[What's wrong to fit periodic data with polynomials?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224990/whats-wrong-to-fit-periodic-data-with-polynomials)

[Why I am getting different predictions for manual polynomial expansion and using the R `poly` function?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276987/why-i-am-getting-different-predictions-for-manual-polynomial-expansion-and-using)

Also, neural network can do the feature engineering for us.

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply this, which variables do you suggest I use a basis expansion for?

Comment: @RichardKublik if you want "accurate" model not "interpretive" model, expansion can be used in all variables. to avoid overfitting, regularization can be used.