# How to correctly predict from orthogonalized covariates on new data in polynomial regression?

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression, polynomial

One option for a polynomial linear regression it to transform a covariate `x` to a matrix of its n-th polynomial and subsequently run a linear regression model. The function `poly` in `R` orthogonalize the columns of this matrix or leave them as they are after polynomial extension (`raw`). I observed choosing to orthogonalize in this was may lead to problems in predictions on **new** data. However orthogonalizing the columns seems important as linear regression suffers when covariates are highly correlated (as do other methods such as Ridge regression).

**An illustration**
I simulate data from a third order polynomial model (black points). Then I fit a linear model using the orthogonal transformation of `poly` and predict using the same data (purple points). Next I choose new data `x_new`, run the orthogonal transformation on it, and predict using the same model. The predictions differ (blue points)!

[image]

As noted by @hdx1011 using the `poly` function within `lm` avoids the problem. So the function internally has a way to deal with it. However in an application I need to implement the matrix product explicitly as in the code below.

So how can I implement this matrix product ( `x_mat %*% as.matrix(coef(mod1))`) or re-scale the matrix `poly(x_new, 3)` to get to the correct predictions?

---

*Code.*

```
n = 1000
x = rnorm(n,0,1)
y = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + rnorm(n)

x_mat = poly(x, 3)
mod1  = lm(y ~ x_mat)
x_mat = cbind(rep(1,n), x_mat)
pred  = x_mat %*% as.matrix(coef(mod1))

x_new     = seq(-3, 3, length.out = 600)
x_mat_new = cbind(rep(1,600), poly(x_new, 3) )
pred_new  = x_mat_new %*% as.matrix(coef(mod1))

plot(x,y)
points(x, pred, col = "purple")
points(x_new, pred_new, col = "blue")
```

Comment: i think I asked a very similar (if not the same) question here. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276987/why-i-am-getting-different-predictions-for-manual-polynomial-expansion-and-using

Comment: @hdx1011 Thanks - do you have the short answer for me? In particular how I can I get correct predictions when predicting on new data with while the columns were orthogolized when estimating the model?

Comment: short answer is using lm(y~poly(x)) instead of doing poly out side of lm

Comment: read the link I sent

Comment: @Firebug In my oppinion this question is inherently about statisitcs, i.e. how to predict. Although the answer turned out to be a programming issue, the underlying problem is really statistical-mathematical and related to how matrices are orthogonalized and how the same orthogonalization can be applied to the covariates matrix of a test set. Furthermore, non-programming answers could consider the mathematical procedure underlying ´poly´.

Comment: @John please see post above

Comment: @PeterFlom please see post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the `coefs` argument of `poly`. The coefficients used in the orthogonal transformation are saved as attributes in a `poly` object. They have to be saved for later use.

In the implementation this will look as follows:

```
n = 1000
x = rnorm(n,0,1)
y = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + rnorm(n)

x_mat = poly(x, 3)
coefs = attr(x_mat,"coefs")                           #save coefficients for later use
mod1  = lm(y ~ x_mat)
x_mat = cbind(rep(1,n), x_mat)
pred  = x_mat %*% as.matrix(coef(mod1))

x_new     = seq(-3, 3, length.out = 600)
x_mat_new = cbind(rep(1,600), poly(x_new, 3, coefs = coefs) ) #use coef argument
pred_new  = x_mat_new %*% as.matrix(coef(mod1)) 

plot(x,y)
points(x, pred, col = "purple")
points(x_new, pred_new, col = "blue")
```

Comment: @hxd1011 perhaps you find this solution interesting